# Display php array with sequential indexes

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a problem I have two arrays, 1 created using php explode function. What I want is to display the number for each word in the array. Below is the code I'm using. The reason I want it so that I can link a mp3 file to each word in the list. 
The file link format to the mp3 are link this: 0000001.mp3, 0000002.mp3, etc.

Currently the arrays are producing starting key values of zero for every array:

```
$a1=array(0=>"Cat",1=>"Dog",2=>"Horse",3=>"House");
$a2=array(0=>"Bird",1=>"Rat",2=>"Fish");
$a3=array(0=>"Horse",1=>"Dog",2=>"Bird");
```

I want the arrays to have keys that continue so that I can link them to a mp3 file  e.g

```
$a1=array(0=>"Cat",1=>"Dog",2=>"Horse",3=>"House");
$a2=array(4=>"Bird",5=>"Rat",6=>"Fish");
$a3=array(7=>"Horse",8=>"Dog",9=>"Bird");
```

check line 15 
p.s I am not a pro at php and I definitely know there are a couple of mistakes in the php code.  http://www.deen-ul-islam.org/quran-player/quran.php

```
foreach ($suraText as $aya) {
    $trans = $transText[$ayaNum- 1];
    // remove bismillahs, except for suras 1 and 9
    if (!$showBismillah && $ayaNum == 1 && $sura !=1 && $sura !=9) {
        $aya = preg_replace('/^(([^ ]+ ){4})/u', '', $aya);
        // display waqf marks in different style
        // $aya = preg_replace('/ ([ۖ-۩])/u', '<span class="sign">&nbsp;$1</span>', $aya);
        $surah2 = leading_zeros($sura, 3);
        $ayaNum2 = leading_zeros($ayaNum, 3);
        $aya = explode(' ',$aya);
        echo "<div class=aya>";
        echo "<div class=quran><a href='http://www.everyayah.com/data/Ghamadi_40kbps/$surah2$ayaNum2.mp3' class='sm2_link'><span class=ayaNum>$ayaNum. </span></a>";
        foreach($aya as $key => $aya) { 
        $key = $key+1; ?>
            <a href="http://audio.allahsquran.com/wbw/<?php echo $key ?>.mp3" class="sm2_link"><span class="word"><?php echo $aya ?></span></a>
            <?php }

            echo  "</div>";
            //echo "<div class=trans>$trans </div>";
            echo "</div>";
            $ayaNum++;
        }
```

Comment: but you have some sort of arrayed results now? which don't have `key` as num, so your `key` is the `value`?

Comment: I read your question three times, and I still don't understand what you've written.  Please edit.

Comment: Please, put only in your question the code relevant to the arrays your asking about. Showing us all of the code is making us to waste time looking through it and after we're identified the bit of code with the problem, we can now work on getting a solution. People here doesn't have all the spare time of the world (although it may seem so sometimes), so please, put only the relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

Use **keys** in your foreach loop:

```
foreach($array as $i=>$item) {
     echo $i.' = '.$item.'<br/>'
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

As far I undestand your question, you should use a code similar to this:

```
foreach ($suraWords as &$word) {
    $word = substr('0000000'.array_search($word, $dictionary),-7).'.mp3';
}
```

where `$dictionary` is an array with all the word you would recognize and `$suraWords` is the array containing the exploded sura.

In this way all your words are translated to the corresponding filename (though I don't assume nothing on efficiency of this solution).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do an [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) of the three arrays? Is there any reason you need to have the information in separate arrays?

That way you would have all the sequential keys as you need them.